# Laravel how to check and avoid duplicated entries in the controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building an `laravel`-application where users among other things can enter their educations. To avoid duplicated entries, I added this to my controller:

```
$user_education = UserEducation::where(['id' => $id, "user_id" => $request->user()->id])->first();

if ($user_education->where(["education_id" => $validated['education_id']])->first() != null) {
     $user_education->education_id = request()->education_id;
     $user_education->education_level_id = $validated['education_level_id'];
     $user_education->is_current = request()->is_current;
     $user_education->start_date = $start_date;
     $user_education->end_date = $end_date;
     $user_education->school = $validated['school'];
     $user_education->description = request()->description;
     $user_education->save();
   } else {
     return response(['errors' => ["education" => ["Education already created."]]], 400);
}
```

but this does not seem to work 100%. When I try to update an existing entry, the data gets updated correctly, but still I get the error message "Education already created"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? You should start by checking when these conditions are met as expected, and when not

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an easier way to accomplish what you want, using Laravel's `Request class`, where you can define your validation logic. So all you need to do is create a new `Request`:

```
php artisan make:request UserEducation
```

Then, amongst other rules, add unique rule, which prevents duplicate entries in database:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true; //Set this to true, or write your own logic to determine if user is authorized to submit this request 
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'education_id' => 'unique:table_name, column_name',
    ];
}
```

This will prevent entering duplicate `education_id` in the column you stated above.

All you have to do now is to include this new request in your controller method:

```
public function update(UserEducation $request){
   //Your logic, don't need an if-else statement, just your save() logic.
}
```

If you have any questions or issues with the solution I provided, let me know. You can read more on [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique).

Answer (score 0):

To check for duplicates of a specific field when updating in a controller using Laravel, you can use a combination of validation rules and database queries. Here's a step-by-step guide:

Create a Custom Request (Optional):

If you haven't already, you can create a custom request to handle validation. Run the following Artisan command to generate one:

```
php artisan make:request UpdateUserEducationRequest
```

Open the generated UpdateUserRequest.php file in the app/Http/Requests directory.

Define Validation Rules:

In your UpdateUserEducationRequest (or directly in the controller if you're not using a custom request), define the validation rules. For example, if you want to check the uniqueness of a username field:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'education_id' => 'required|unique:user_education,education_id,' . $this->route('id'),
        // Other validation rules...
    ];
}
```

In the above example, unique:user_education,education_id checks that the education_id is unique in the user_education table. The third parameter ' . $this->route('id') is used to ignore the current user_education's ID when checking for uniqueness. This assumes you're passing the user_education ID in the route.

Use the Request in Your Controller:

If you created a custom request, you can now use it in your controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserEducationRequest;

// ...

public function update(UpdateUserEducationRequest $request, $id)
{
    // Validation has already been performed at this point.

    // Retrieve the user
    $user_education = UserEducation::findOrFail($id);

    // Update user attributes
    $user_education->education_id= $request->input('education_id');
    // Add other attributes as needed

    // Save the updated user
    $user_education->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'UserEducation updated successfully']);
}
```

If you're not using a custom request, you can perform the validation directly in your controller.

Update the Route:

In your routes file (usually routes/api.php), make sure you have a route set up to handle the update request:

```
Route::put('/user_education/{id}', 'UserEducationController@update');
```

This assumes you're using a UserEducationController with an update method.

With these steps, when you try to update a user_education, the validation will check if the education_id is unique, excluding the current user_education's ID. If the validation fails, Laravel will respond with an error message. If it passes, you can proceed with updating the user_education.